# no applicable method for 'extract_parameter_set_dials' applied to an object of class "workflow"

Tags: r, tidymodels

Following the excelent book *Tidy modeling with R*, [Section 14.1](https://www.tmwr.org/iterative-search.html#svm), the authors present a case of a SVM model hyperparameter tuning:

```r
library(tidymodels)
tidymodels_prefer()
data(cells, package = "modeldata")
cells <- cells[, -1] # remove case column

svm_rec <- 
  recipe(class ~ ., data = cells) %>%
  step_YeoJohnson(all_numeric_predictors()) %>%
  step_normalize(all_numeric_predictors())

svm_spec <- 
  svm_rbf(cost = tune(), rbf_sigma = tune()) %>% 
  set_engine("kernlab") %>% 
  set_mode("classification")

svm_wflow <- 
  workflow() %>% 
  add_model(svm_spec) %>% 
  add_recipe(svm_rec)
```

Afterwards, they ilustrate how to change the kernel parameter range, to improve the visualizations of the search:

```r
svm_param <- 
  svm_wflow %>% 
  extract_parameter_set_dials() %>% 
  update(rbf_sigma = rbf_sigma(c(-7, -1)))
```

But this results in an error:

```r
Error in UseMethod("extract_parameter_set_dials") : 
  no applicable method for 'extract_parameter_set_dials' applied to an object of class "workflow"
```

Is this due to an update in the tidymodels framework? What woul be the correct way to extract and modify the hyperparameters range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [tidymodels](/questions/tagged/tidymodels) packages recently had releases of [dials](https://dials.tidymodels.org/news/index.html) and other packages (like workflows) that added this new generic:

```r
library(tidymodels)
tidymodels_prefer()
data(cells, package = "modeldata")
cells <- cells[, -1] # minus case

svm_rec <- recipe(class ~ ., data = cells) |> 
    step_YeoJohnson(all_numeric_predictors()) |> 
    step_normalize(all_numeric_predictors())

svm_spec <- svm_rbf(cost = tune(), rbf_sigma = tune()) |> 
    set_engine("kernlab") |> 
    set_mode("classification")

svm_wflow <- workflow() |> 
    add_model(svm_spec) |> 
    add_recipe(svm_rec)

svm_wflow |> 
    extract_parameter_set_dials() |>
    update(rbf_sigma = rbf_sigma(c(-7, -1)))
#> Collection of 2 parameters for tuning
#> 
#>  identifier      type    object
#>        cost      cost nparam[+]
#>   rbf_sigma rbf_sigma nparam[+]
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

You can [read more here](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2022/04/tidymodels-2022-q1/#new-parameter-objects-and-parameter-handling), and we recommend updating your packages from CRAN.